# Getting mailman3 to play nicely with postfix and dovecot

Tags: email, postfix, mailman

I am playing around with mailman3 and I've happened upon this problem: mailman3, the web interface as well as hyperkitty have been installed using mailman-bundler. I have added the prescribed postfix configuration to `main.cf`:

```
recipient_delimiter = +
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
owner_request_special = no
transport_maps = hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_lmtp
local_recipient_maps = hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_lmtp
relay_domains = hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_domains
```

The listed files are world-readable so there should not be a permission problem. I can successfully create a domain/list via the web interface, but when I try to send mail to the list address the mail is rejected with the following message:

`Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table`

This postfix installation normally uses a `virtual_transport` to deliver mail to dovecot. The corresponding configuration looks like this:

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
```

This is based on the excellent [NSA-proof your e-mail in 2 hours](http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsa-proof-your-e-mail-in-2-hours/) guide.

Now, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432375/postfix-transport-maps-and-virtual-mailbox) claims that `virtual_transport` and `transport_maps` do not play nicely together, although I can't find anything in the postfix documentation that verifies this claim. The author has resolved their issue by just using `transport_maps` which does not seem to be an option for me.

Note that I also get a warning that the `local_recipient_maps` option from mailman3 overrides the earlier definition as part of the dovecot delivery. This can be solved by specifying both values on one line as such:

```
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_lmtp
```

But that does not solve the problem. Does anyone have any ideas or experience in making this work? I realize that mailman3 is still considered new. That's why I'm playing with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured this one out. Turns out the claims in the linked StackOverflow question were false. It is indeed possible to use `virtual_transport` and `transport_maps` together. My problem was the SQL query used to determine `virtual_mailbox_maps` would naturally only return `1` when the mailbox was defined in the database. As soon as that check failed, the message was rejected.

```sql
-- from: mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE name = 'name = '%s'
```

Adding the mailman3 mapping to the `virtual_mailbox_maps` setting solved the issue for me. This is my working configuration:

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_lmtp
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
local_recipient_maps = hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_lmtp mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
transport_maps = hash:/path/to/var/data/postfix_lmtp
```

It sets up `virtual_transport` to *default* to dovecot but allows it to be overriden by `transport_maps` which maps the list addresses to the mailman local transport.

Comment: Thank you for the hint towards `transport_maps`! I actually got it to work with just adding the mailmain files to `virtual_mailbox_domains`, `virtual_mailbox_maps` and `transport_maps`.